# Refreshing an entire Linq to SQL DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, refresh

I am maintaining an application in C# that instantiates a DataContext at the outset and uses it throughout. I am finding that when one user makes changes, those changes are not reflected on another user's system when they reload their forms (it's a WinForms app). I think the root problem is that the data is being cached on the second user's system due to the perpetually open DataContext.

Given that the application cannot be rewritten to use granular DataContexts (which would probably be the correct solution), I'm looking at the Refresh() method as a way to work around the problem. The problem is that to really get the results I want, I would like to refresh the entire DataContext. Obviously, that's not provided as an option, but what can I do to get that effect? Does the Refresh() method cascade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UnitOfwork` pattern in this scenario.
what it basically do is to perform all action as an transaction.